# Google Analytics podspec

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods

The podspec file for Google Analytics for iOS 3.09 from here:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK/3.0.9/GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK.podspec.json

gives the following error when I run 'pod install':

[!] Invalid `GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK.podspec` file: /Users/me/workspace/iOS/techlingo/Pods/Local Podspecs/GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK.podspec:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
  "name": "GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK",

Anyone successfully using Cocoapods and Google Analytics 3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to reference the SDK located in a separate directory. Removing that directory reference got me past the problem.